# How to find custom field name to write a wp all import php function

Tags: php, function, wpallimport

I need to set to null or 0 the price field from the XMl if a fiel called Trattativa_riservata=SI. If is NO, it leaves the price value as is from the XML.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Can you show what you're tried so far to achieve this ?

Comment: Hi Welcome on SO. Please read [mcve] and update your answer, so someone can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution with this simple PHP code:

```
function private_negotiation($negotiation, $price){
    if ($negotiation == 'SI') {
        $price = 0;
        }
    return $price;
}
```

Thanks to all